# Read all lines in .txt that are all upper or all lower case Python 2.7.1?

Tags: python, element, lines, skip

I'm trying to read all lines of a file that are either all upper or all lower case.

If `file.txt` contains:

```
Rememberr 8? when you
. Tellingmee THAT one
didntrememberthat
onethingtoday
```

I would want it to read:

```
didntrememberthat
ONETHINGTODAY
```

So far I have:

```
def function(file_name):
    data=[]
    f=open(file_name,'r')
    lines=f.readlines()
    for k in lines:
        single=tuple(k)
        for j in single:
            j=str(j)
            if j.isupper() or j.islower() == False:
            lines=f.readlines()[j:]
```

Then i get this:

```
lines=f.readlines()[j:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

which makes sense because `j` isn't an integer. But how would i find the position of `j` when it encounters the `if`-statement?

If there is an easier way to do it that would be awesome

Comment: Do you really want `onethingtoday` converted to all-caps?

Comment: @ Marcelos . It was supposed to be f not in_file . I changed it . The files i will be read with the script will either be in all upper or all lower

Comment: You can't call `readlines()` multiple times on the same file object. It consumes the input.

Comment: hm . . so the function f.readlines()[1:] would show all lines after 1 . How would you do a code it to read all lines after the line that is not all upper or lower case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def homogeneous_lines (file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            if line.islower() or line.isupper():
                yield line
```

This function reads through every line in the file. Then for every line checks to see if the line is all upper or lower case.

Finally we yield the line.

EDIT - Changed to incorporate using with statement, use builtin islower() and isupper() for strings, and made into a generator.

Comment: You could just use `c.islower()` instead of `c == c.lower()`. And if you then open file using `with`, and make that function a generator, you get an upvote from me =).

Comment: You should `close` the file after using it. And you are reimplementing `line.islower()` and `line.isupper()` =)

Comment: @BjörnPollex Fixed I believe. Incorporated changes and made into generator. Thanks.

Comment: @moooeeeep Fixed with with statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error because j is a string, not an integer (you don't have to call `str(j)`, by the way; it's already a string).

You can remove lines with a mix of upper- and lower-case like this:

```
all_one_case = [ line
                 for line in f.readlines()
                 if line.isupper() or line.islower() ]
```

Note: Credit for the use of `isupper()` and `islower()` (The original used `re`.) goes to some other answers to this question.

This will also include, e.g., `10 green bottles`, since it only contains lowercase letters, even though it also contains digits and spaces. From the question, I can't tell whether this is the intent or not. If you want only letters, you can use this test instead:

```
               … if re.match('[A-Z]*$|[a-z]*$', line) ]
```

If you want to replace the file with these lines, you can reopen it for writing:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in all_one_case:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

If in one line you can have only one symbol then I do not know why do you convert line (`k`) into tuple, and 2nd call to `f.readlines()` is probably bug. After 1st call of `f.readlines()` you have all lines in `lines` variable and in loop you can check it line by line.

If you want to check is whole string is lowercase or uppercase, then use such code:

```
if line.islower() or line.isupper():
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use list comprehensions:

```
f=open(file_name,'r')

lines = f.readlines()

ul_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in lines if line.islower() or line.isupper()]
```

You should tweak it if your file is unicode, but that's the general idea.

The rstrip part is to get rid of '\n' at the end.

Also, more memory efficient version

```
f=open(file_name,'r')

ul_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f if line.islower() or line.isupper()]
```

You'll have to reopen the file to repeat it though.

If you are very memory constrained you should use a generator expression:

```
f=open(file_name,'r')

ul_lines_gen = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in f if line.islower() or line.isupper())
```

And if you want only letters and no digits in your strings add line.rstrip('\n').isalpha() condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open(file_name,'r')
print [l for l in f.readlines() if l.islower() or l.isupper()]
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `with` statement for `open` the file. This way you are be safe that the file will get `close`d even in case of an exception.
Use the string methods `islower` and `isupper` to check whether the string is all upper or lower case. For example like this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
  output = [line for line in f if line.isupper() or line.islower()]
```